# How to make 'Products' tab appear in Salesforce1 Navigation Sidebar

Tags: configuration, navigation, salesforce

I am trying to get the 'Products' tab to appear in the navigation side bar in salesforce1.  I can see how to get custom object tabs to appear, and the answers I've found on here so far only appear to be for custom objects. but I cannot find a similar solution for standard objects.

Viewing mobile navigation customization doesn't appear to show the products tab to add to the navigation sidebar.

I am a little new to Salesforce1 so it's entirely possible I've missed something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done yet. Please vote up here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxxfAAA